Vanishing app icons. What is the color threshold at which iOS 18 will generate a dark icon?
If you want to build for iOS18, you can upgrade to XCode16 which allows you to build dark and tinted variants, as per Apple's docs
If you are currently still building with XCode15, you may have a problem where your app icon vanishes in dark mode. My icon looks great on iOS17 in both light and dark modes.

However, when built to an iOS18 device, the icon vanishes in dark mode, being replaced by a missing icon image.
Reading questions such as this one did not help - my attempts to change Content.json to include extra images didn't work.
But the comment It seems that Apple does some AI magic to convert some icons automatically into dark mode icon. did spark some inspiration.
I tried changing my background from a gradient to a solid fill. That didn't work. Then I used a lighter fill color and that was the key.
Magic Fill Threshold?
There is apparently some cutoff at which the magic stops. The image below shows the light mode Purrticles icon and the auto-generated dark one. The light is a fill of ACBDFF and I don't like the lilac tone. Trying 2A4DFF was too dark as was 7CB5FF.

Using a light fill of 99C6FF works too but is also losing the contrast of the original design.
I included this second pair of screenshots to show how dramatically a small variation in light colour affects the generated dark one!

ACBDFF generates 1841dd
99C6FF generates 78a5dc

The turnaround of tweaking colours and rebuilding the app is frustrating. Does anyone have any information or hints on how to work out the threshold at which this tips over?
I may have to just give up and install XCode16 :-(

